# Entity Framework automatically creating many to many join table and ignoring mine

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to set up a join table with payload for a many-to-many. I have the following entities and fluent APIs which I would expect to override this automatic interference. But EF keeps creating its own version of the table without a payload and using that for the relationship. How can I stop it doing this please!

Using EF6.

```
    public class Property
    {
        public int PropertyId { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ShowcaseUser> ShowcaseUsers{ get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual ICollection<ShowcaseUserProperties> ShowcaseUserProperties { get; set; }

    public class ShowcaseUser : IdentityUser
    {
        // IdentityUser contains string Id as its id
        public virtual ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual ICollection<ShowcaseUserProperties> ShowcaseUserProperties { get; set; }
    }

public class ShowcaseUserProperties
{
    public string ShowcaseUser_Id { get; set; }

    public int Property_PropertyId { get; set; }        

    public bool Subscribed { get; set; }

    public virtual Property Property { get; set; }
    public virtual ShowcaseUser ShowcaseUser { get; set; }
}

     modelBuilder.Entity<ShowcaseUserProperties>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.ShowcaseUser_Id, c.Property_PropertyId }).ToTable("ShowcaseUserProperties");

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShowcaseUserProperties>()
                .HasRequired(t=>t.Property)
                .WithMany(t=>t.ShowcaseUserProperties)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.Property_PropertyId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ShowcaseUserProperties>()
                .HasRequired(t => t.ShowcaseUser)
                .WithMany(t => t.ShowcaseUserProperties)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t.ShowcaseUser_Id);
```

[image: sql screenshot]

Comment: I assume there are no mutual collection properties in both entities (like `Property.ShowcaseUsers`?

Comment: Can you post your complete classes, I suspect you have another reference to each other besides ShowcaseUserProperties

Comment: You're right..I did have the other field references. I'm guessing that's causing 2 relationships?

Comment: Yes, you can either have a true many to many association (with `Property.ShowcaseUsers` and reverse, and transparent junction table), or 1-n-1, with `ShowcaseUserProperties` as junction class that's visible in the class model.